# How to make a letter move foward by one space with Javascript?

Tags: javascript

For example, I got this :
`_T___`
And I want to move the T foward by one space and destroy the next letter like this:
`__T__`
Is it possible? If it's possible then how can I do this using Javascript? Thanks a lot!

Comment: And what goes into the space that 'T' was in prior?

Comment: I got this `_T___` sorry, where? Some HTML element, a variable string? Can you show some code? How is that supposed to work? Have you tried anything?

Comment: If its not a huge string, you can split it to an array and and swap the T around. and then use .join on the array. But there could be better ways experts may know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a function that returns the string given the position you want "T" to be in.

```
function positionT(index, length){ 
  var str = ''; 
  for(var i=0; i< length; i++){
    if(i===index){
      str+='T'
    } else {
      str+='_'
    }}  
  return str; 
}

positionT(1,5)  // returns "_T___"
positionT(2,5) // returns  "__T__"
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
// To "destroy" the next letter and insert a default "_" where the "T" was:
console.log( "abcdTefg".replace(/T.?/, "_T") )
console.log( "____T___".replace(/T.?/, "_T") )
// The ? in the regex allows for the "T" being at the end:
console.log( "_______T".replace(/T.?/, "_T") )

// To simply swap the "T" with the character that follows:
console.log( "abcdTefg".replace(/T(.)/, "$1T") )
console.log( "____T___".replace(/T(.)/, "$1T") )
// No change if "T" is at the end, because there's no letter to swap with:
console.log( "abcdefgT".replace(/T(.)/, "$1T") )
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var str = 'T____';

let i=5;
while(i--){
  console.log(i, str=moveLetter(str) );
}


function moveLetter(str){
  return str.replace(/^(.*?)([^_])(.)(.*)$/,"$1$3$2$4")
}
```

Of course if you wanted a newer (ES6) way:

```js
let str = '_T____',
  len = str.length;

function moveLetter(str) {
  let arr = str.split(''),
    pos = str.search(/[^_]/);
  
  // swap array elements
  [arr[pos], arr[pos+1]] = [arr[pos+1], arr[pos]];
  return arr.join('');
}

while (len--)
  console.log(len, str = moveLetter(str));
```

Comment: I think you wanted `while(--i)`

Comment: @rasmeister The iterator isn't really tied to the string length, I just needed something to quickly demonstrate what happens when the letter gets to the end of the string — in this case, nothing.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var mystring = "1234T56";
console.log("Before:", mystring);
var indexOfT = mystring.indexOf("T"); //Get where t is in the string
mystring = mystring.split("T").join(''); //remove the t from the string
mystring = mystring.split(''); // turn string into an array
mystring[indexOfT] = 'T'; //add T back in one index down
mystring = mystring.join(''); //return the array to a string
console.log("After:", mystring);
```

Comment: But in the "after" the "T" is still in the same place, at index 4.